# How to yield Mobx.autorun to prevent firing in class constructor?

Tags: javascript, typescript, mobx

In this class I use a initialized bool state to yield the Mobx.autorun execution. Otherwize 'this' is not totally assigned and leads to errors. Is there another/cleaner way to do this?

```
class GameMaster{

  private _initialized:boolean = false;
  private _store:IDomainStore;
  private _moveDisposer:Lambda;

  /**
   *
   * @param store - client or server store
   */
    constructor(store:IDomainStore){
        this._store = store;
        console.log(this._store);
        //todo abstract services to decouple client device from GameMaster because it is also used on the server.
        this._moveDisposer = autorun(()=>{
          // prevent firing in the constructor
          if(this._initialized) {
            this.present(
              <IIntent>{
                fromId: 'GeoLocation.service',
                toIds: [Meteor.userId()],
                wish: actions.playerActions.types.CHANGE_PLAYER_GEO_COORDINATES,
                data: [System.GeolocationService.coordinates.lng, System.GeolocationService.coordinates.lat]
            });
          }
        });
        this._initialized = true;
      }

    public present(intent:IIntent):boolean{
      ...
    }
 ...
}
```

This is my observable in another file:

```
 @observable coordinates = {
    lng:0,
    lat:0
  };
```

Comment: Can you indicate which variables are decorated as observable? I would expect the autorun not to fire at all in your current setup.

Comment: And `coordinates` is probably fired indeed during the construction or maybe autorun is run once for initialization purpose?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is a fine approach to the problem, however the initialized field should be observable as well. Otherwise changing `_initialized` will not cause the autorun to re-run.

But in that case I'm not sure what the initialized variable exactly achieves in your, because your first statement after the autorun is to set initialized to true?

So i'm not entirely sure what you are to achieve: postpone the autorun / `present` call to the end of the constructor, or to skip the first `present` call?

**Updated answer**

If you want to prevent the side effect (sending `present` in this case) there is a simple pattern for that. The clue is to make sure that you compute any value which is needed for the side effect, but don't trigger the side effect yourself. So in your example this would look

```
constructor(store:IDomainStore){
    let firstRun = true;
    this._moveDisposer = autorun(()=>{
        // make sure all information is tracked
        const presenceInfo = <IIntent>{
            fromId: 'GeoLocation.service',
            toIds: [Meteor.userId()],
            wish: actions.playerActions.types.CHANGE_PLAYER_GEO_COORDINATES,
            data: [System.GeolocationService.coordinates.lng, System.GeolocationService.coordinates.lat]
        }
        // but prevent the side effect in the first run
        if(!firstRun) {
            this.present(presenceInfo);
        } else {
            firstRun = false;
        }
    });
  }
```

(note that the flag might not be needed in the future anymore, as there is an existing [proposal](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx/issues/209) to pass a param `firstRun` to the autorunned function).

Comment: I want to prevent autorun to trigger its function without observable change. Because present() use some instance variables that are not usable before the end of the constructor call.

Comment: Autorun behavior is to run once even its dependencies has not changed. Is not?

Comment: I mean at initialization.

Comment: Correction: if I set `_initialized` as an observable I will run in the same problem as autorun will be fired before the end of the constructor call. I will simply wait for the service to send another coordinates change.

Comment: smart! I was close. Thx you. Although I think I was looking for the firstRun proposal after all.